# Remove extra space from Modal

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

I want to remove this extra space coming into my modal. How to remove this? I am using the standard slds modal and browser zoom @100%

Inspecting it shows slds-modal__content class is having height: 90% !important

Whats the best way to remove it?

**LWC:**

```
  <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-02" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" onclick={closeModal}>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
      </button>
      <div class="slds-modal__header">
        <h1 id="modal-heading-02" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">{modalHeading}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-modal__content " id="modal-content-id-2">

          <!--some content here -->
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer slds-align_absolute-center">
          <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" label="Cancel" onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button><span>&nbsp;</span>
          <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" label="Update" onclick={update} variant="brand"></lightning-button>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard `lightning-modal` component you can use: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation

That will not have the extra space at the bottom.